# Is there transliteration from UTF-8 to CP1251 when one symbol substitutes with several symbols?

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding, iconv, windows-1251

I use function iconv with option translit.

Is there transliteration from UTF-8 to CP1251 when one symbol substitutes with several symbols?
Where I can search for that information? I am using iconv.

Comment: By "symbol" do you mean *character*?

Comment: Transliteration has nothing to do with encoding. Encoding - is a way how to represent some character (code point) in binary form, while transliteration is a process of replacement characters of one alphabet with characters of another alphabet e.g. cyrillic letters with latin ones. Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: For example, according to [link](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php) (russian)  if i use iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT" to string "€", I get as result string "EUR". But when i try this to convert to CP1251, i get �. And I'm intresting, is there some characters that transliterates in serverel characters in cp1251

Comment: I think you could probably use [std::codecvt_byname](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_byname).

Comment: You don't really get �, you get € in CP1251, [which is character number 0x88](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251), but your UTF-8 terminal/editor/whatever has no idea how to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some, depending on the implementation and locale:

```
$ echo '℀⇒½' | iconv -f UTF8 -t CP1251//TRANSLIT
a/c=> 1/2
```

These are, respectively, **U+2100** <kbd>ACCOUNT OF</kbd> transliterated as `a/c`, **U+21D2** <kbd>RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW</kbd> transliterated as `=>`, **U+00BD**<kbd>VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF</kbd> transliterated as `1/2` (including spaces).

I found these in the GNU libc source code, https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/locale/C-translit.h.in; different implementations may not transliterate these characters the same way if at all.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious one is

```
$ echo 'ß' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t CP1251//TRANSLIT
ss
```

In addition, if your locale is German, umlauts are transliterated according to German rules (yes transliteration is locale dependent).

```
$ export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
$ echo 'Füße' | iconv -f utf-8 -t CP1251//TRANSLIT
Fuesse
```

(Some versions will print `F"usse` instead).